# Change the color theme of Kivy's FileChooser

Tags: python, kivy

For some reason, the [FileChooser Popup](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html) comes with a dark theme by default. How can it be changed to a normal/bright theme without manually redefining the appearance of each and every element in the kv style file?

Side note: I don't understand why Kivy comes with dark default colors in the first place, and why there is no easy way to change it. Not even [MD themes](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD) appear to be convenient, because they require to rewrite all standard classes (e.g. `MDRaisedButton` instead of `Button`). But maybe these are topics for another discussion...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
Builder.load_string('''
<FileChooserListView>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.5,0,0,1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
''')
```

to add a little color.